# Laravel like not working - like in where ('key','lke','%'.key.'%')

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

In my Laravel project like the query is not working.

There is no output for the following code.

```
$data['result'] = Songs::where('is_active','=','1')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');

if (!empty($key)) {
    $data['result'] = $data['result']->where('key','LIKE',DB::raw("CONCAT('%', $key, '%')"));
}
```

Please help me to solve this

***I have also tried the following***

`->where('sale_property.property_ref_id', 'LIKE', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', $key, '%')"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do some more query, just try to put ->get() at the last.

Heres the example:

```
$data['result'] = Songs::where('is_active','=','1')->orderBy('created_at','DESC');

if (!empty($key)) {
    $data['result'] = $data['result']->where('key','LIKE','%'. $key .'%');
}

$data['result'] = $data['result']->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but you can add a bit of beauty from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```php
$data['result'] = Songs::where('is_active', '1')
->when($key, function ($query, $key) {
    return $query->where('key', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%');
})->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```